# finding the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for $y=(e^{x^{2+1}})^{sin(x)}$

Tags: calculus

I'm calculating for the derivative on this exercise, and would kindly appreciate feedback on my solution and especially on whether my solution can be simplified further if correct.

$$y =(e^{x^{2+1}})^{sin(x)}$$

My calculation:

Take the natural log of both sides:

$$\ln(y)=\sin(x)\ln(e^{x^{2+1}})$$

Then taking the derivative of both sides and applying the product rule $fg'+f'g$ in respect to $x$.

$$\frac{1}{y}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=\sin(x)\frac{2x}{e^{x^{2+1}}}+\cos(x)\ln(e^{x^{2+1}})$$

transporting $y$ onto the right side to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and substituting in the value $(e^{x^{2+1}})^{sin(x)}$ for $y$

$$(e^{x^{2+1}})^{sin(x)}[\sin(x)\frac{2x}{e^{x^{2+1}}}+\cos(x)\ln(e^{x^{2+1}})] = \frac{2x\sin(x)(e^{x^{2+1}})^{sin(x)}}{e^{x^{2+1}}}+\cos(x)(e^{x^{2+1}})^{sin(x)}\ln(e^{x^{2+1}})=\frac{(e^{x^{2+1}})^{sin(x)}[2x\sin(x)]+(e^{x^{2+1}})^{sin(x)}[\cos(x)(e^{x^{2+1}})\ln(e^{x^{2+1}})]}{e^{x^{2+1}}}$$

Comment: Why don't you simplify $x^{2+1}=x^3$

Comment: Why don't you just use the derivative formula: $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)^{g(x)}= \left( f \left( x \right)  \right) ^{g \left( x \right) } \left( 
 \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}g \left( x \right)  \right) \ln 
 \left( f \left( x \right)  \right) +{\frac {g \left( x \right) {
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}f \left( x \right) }{f \left( x \right) }}
 \right) 
$. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_rules#Generalized_power_rule

Comment: @BernardMassé Thanks for this! I tried it out, and noticed that I missed $e^{x^{2+1}}$ on the left-addition of the final numerator. This is definitely a cleaner-method, and I'll be using it more often.

Comment: Alternatively, the reason you took the log of both sides should have been to reduce $\ln(e^{x^3})=x^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to ease derivation it is convenient to simplify $y=y(x)$ at first.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{dy}{dx}}&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{x^3}\right)^{\sin(x)}\\
> &=\frac{d}{dx}e^{x^3\sin(x)}\tag{1}\\
> &=\left(\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sin(x)x^3\right)\right)e^{x^3\sin(x)}\tag{2}\\
> &=\left(3x^2\sin(x)+x^3\cos(x)\right)e^{x^3\sin(x)}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=x^2\left(3\sin(x)+x\cos(x)\right)e^{x^3\sin(x)}}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the rule $\left(p^{q^r}\right)^s=\left(p^{\left(q^r\right)}\right)^s=p^{\left(sq^r\right)}$.
- In (2) we apply $\left(e^{f(x)}\right)^{\prime}=f^{\prime}(x)e^{f(x)}$.